# How to reset game with new enemy?

Tags: javascript, loops, readline

So, I am building a basic command line game using readline-sync.
The basic premise is you fighting an enemy and if you kill the enemy, the game keeps going and you fight another, if you die the game ends.

My issue is that when I kill the enemy and the game keeps going, it's still with the same enemy and with the same enemy health. How can I get it so that when I kill an enemy, a new enemy comes in with 100 health and I fight him?

I think I get that I have only created one enemy out of the constructor, but is there a way to make it so that it recreates a brand new enemy with 100 health when an enemy dies?

Here's my JavaScript:

```
var readline = require("readline-sync");

function Player(name, hp, items){
    this.name = name;
    this.health = hp;
    this.items = items;
}

function Enemy(name, hp, items){
    this.name = name;
    this.health = hp;
    this.items = items;
}

//1 in 3 chance of getting attacked
var enemyAttacking = ["safe", "safe", "attack"];

//1 in 2 chance of escaping when running
var escaped = [1, 2];

//aren't getting attacked message
var noAttackMes = ["You didn't run into any monsters. Move along...", "No creatures along the pathway. Continue walking.", "You're all alone. Keep going." , "Enemies are not engaging you. Keep walking.", "The path is clear for you. Continue your journey.", "Enemies are nearby, but are not attacking. Keep walking"];

 //randomly chooses a weapon for the enemy to have
 var weapon = ["axe", "sword", "bow and arrow"];
 var weaponSelected = Math.floor(Math.random() * weapon.length);

 //randomly chooses an enemy
 var enemies = ["giant", "dark wizard", "wolf"];
 var enemyChosen = Math.floor(Math.random() * enemies.length);
 var newEnemy = new Enemy(enemies[enemyChosen], 100, weapon[weaponSelected]);

 //randomly choose an amount of hp to remove
 var hpRemove = [20, 40, 60, 80];

//greeting player
var playerName = readline.question("\nGreetings! Welcome to the Seven Kingdoms! In order to gain passage, you must tell me your name: ");
var newPlayer = new Player(playerName, 100, "none");
console.log(`\nGreetings ${playerName}! You have been granted access, but beware of all the nasty beasts and creatures that lurk in the shadows...`);

//will run walk() until player dies
while(newPlayer.health > 0){
    walk();
}

function walk(){  
    var playerWalk = readline.question("\nPlease press 'w' to walk or type 'print' to view inventory: ");
     if(playerWalk === "w"){
         if(enemyAttacking[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemyAttacking.length)] === "attack"){
             console.log("You're being attacked!");
             fight();
         } else {
             console.log(noAttackMes[Math.floor(Math.random() * noAttackMes.length)]);
         }
     }else if(playerWalk === "print") {
         console.log("Here's what's in your inventory:");
         console.log(newPlayer);   
    }
}

function enemyAttack(){
    if(newEnemy.health <= 0){
        console.log(`\nYou have killed the ${enemies[enemyChosen]}! He has dropped his ${weapon[weaponSelected]} and you can now reclaim it as your own.`);
    }else {
        newPlayer.health -= hpRemove[Math.floor(Math.random() * hpRemove.length)];
        console.log(`\nThe ${enemies[enemyChosen]} has attacked you back! Your health now stands at ${newPlayer.health}.`);
    }

    if(newPlayer.health <= 0){
        console.log(`\nYou have died the most gruesome of gruesome deaths. Do not be ashamed, as you fought with honor, and will be welcomed to Valhalla with open arms.`);
    }
}

function fight(){
    var fightOrFlight = ["Fight", "Run"];
    var fightChoice = readline.keyInSelect(fightOrFlight, `The ${enemies[enemyChosen]} is attacking you! What do you want to do?!`);

    if(fightChoice === 0){
        attackEnemy();
    }else {
        run();
    }

    while(newEnemy.health > 0 && newPlayer.health > 0){
        var fightChoice2 = readline.keyInSelect(fightOrFlight, `You have both taken hits. What will you like to do next?`);
        if(fightChoice2 === 0){
            attackEnemy();
        }else {
            run();
        }
    }
}

function run(){
    if(escaped[Math.floor(Math.random() * escaped.length)] === 1){
        console.log("\nYou have escaped the creature and may continue walking!");
    }else {
        console.log("\nYou have not escaped! The creature is attacking!");
        attackEnemy();
    }
}

function attackEnemy(){
    newEnemy.health -= hpRemove[Math.floor(Math.random() * hpRemove.length)];
    console.log(`\nYou have attacked the ${enemies[enemyChosen]}! His health now stands at ${newEnemy.health}.`);
    if(newEnemy.health <= 0){
        newPlayer.items = newEnemy.items;
        newPlayer.health += 20;
    }
    enemyAttack();
}
```

Comment: I believe you have two options here, you can destroy the enemy object when the health reaches or is below 0, and then re-instantiate it. Or you can grab the enemy health attribute, and change its value back to a value that you desire, when the health reaches or is below 0.

Comment: Well... you only have your new Enemy defined at the top, you need an EnemySpawn event or something like that where you reAssign or renitialize that variable

Comment: try to add `newEnemy = new Enemy(enemies[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemies.length);], 100, weapon[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapon.length)]);` inside the condition `if(newEnemy.health <= 0){`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé I had to adjust a few things and then i added your code and that seemed to do it. If you put it as an Answer, I'll mark it as Correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recreate a new Enemy, you can add this code :

`newEnemy = new Enemy(
     enemies[Math.floor(Math.random() * enemies.length);], 
     100, 
     weapon[Math.floor(Math.random() * weapon.length)]
);`

inside the condition `if(newEnemy.health <= 0){`